# Call to Microsoft SQL Server function from VB6 code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb6

I am developing Visual Basic 6 code for call to a Microsoft SQL Server function, but...I can't get it do work ...

The T-SQL code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRutaFichero](@ID_FICHERO VARCHAR(256))
   RETURNS varchar(256)
AS
   .
   .
   .
   RETURN (@rutaFichero)
END
```

The VB6 code:

```
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = cStrConn
cnn.Open "File Name=" & App.Path & "\Config\VCH2.udl;"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandTimeout = 15
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT fnRutaFichero(@ID_FICHERO)"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ID_FICHERO", adVarChar, adParamInput, , "VCH2")

cmd.Execute
```

I don't understand how to do this task...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would make a command = a resordset.

```
Set objRs = objCmd.Execute
```

Here's the programmers guide [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675065(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also not all commands can be done via ADODB according to the docs [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Use a Command object to query a database and return records in a Recordset object, to execute a bulk operation, or to manipulate the structure of a database. Depending on the functionality of the provider, some Command collections, methods, or properties may generate an error when they are referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a return value added to the list of parameters, and you have to include the size of the VarChar field:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@rutaFichero", adVarChar, adParamReturnValue, 256)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ID_FICHERO", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, "VCH2")
```

Comment: `adParamReturnValue` has to be `adInteger` for MSSQL stored procedures.

Comment: @wqw this is a user defined function, not a stored procedure.